# OP_CHECKSIG signature hash type 0

Tags: script, signature, transaction-verification

On the Bitcoin Wiki's [OP_CHECKSIG documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=OP_CHECKSIG&oldid=57808):

> Firstly always this (the default) procedure is applied:
>
> 1. the public key and the signature are popped from the stack, in that order. **If the hash-type value is 0, then it is replaced by the last_byte of the signature. Then the last byte of the signature is always deleted.**

The signature format is:

> 0x30 [total-length] 0x02 [R-length] [R] 0x02 [S-length] [S] [sighash]

In case if hash type is 0 then we should  get last byte from [S] 
and remove it **I think it will corrupt signature**!

Maybe I don't correctly understand this documentation. Could anybody explain the correct behavior in this case?

Comment: Methinks it should say copy, not replace.

Comment: I this error in specification?

Comment: @user15358 I don't see this text in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG anymore.

Comment: Fair warning, the bitcoin wiki is often the summation of years of unverified brain dumps. A non negligible portion is out of date or was never correct to begin with.

Comment: I'm curious to know how this works, as there's a test vector with a SIGHASH of 00 that I can't verify using pybitcointools. It seems changing the 0 to a 1 won't work; there's no real reason why is there?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie, changing the SIGHASH type will invalidate the signature, as it changes the hash that is signed.

Comment: @StephenM347 OK, so that's because the signed Tx form has the hash type appended; but if the SIGHASH type is `0`, why does it act as `1`?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie, not sure exactly what Bitcoin Core's behavior is with non-standard sighash types.

Comment: I've done some testing with pybitcointools and [one of the BitcoinCore test vectors](https://github.com/simcity4242/pybitcointools/blob/master/tests/tx_valid.json#L20-L23) with a SIGHASH of zero. See Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/1Bqd0zbc). I have no idea how this works, since we're hashing the **final transaction** (ie including the signature), which returns the TxID `c99c49da4c38af669dea436d3e73780dfdb6c1ecf9958baa52960e8baee30e73`. This makes no sense whatsoever, anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: @sipa Can you comment [on the above comment](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38971/op-checksig-signature-hash-type-0#comment45869_38971) of mine?

Answer (score 2):

I've done some testing with pybitcointools and one of the BitcoinCore test vectors with a SIGHASH of zero.

For `SIGHASH =0`, the [Tx which is signed](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/blob/master/bitcoin/transaction.py#L178)

It's just a matter of appending 4 nullbytes, instead of `01000000`, to the signing transaction.

The Core software checks for this non-standard hashtype now, however we can see there's no problem in validating these rare transactions since the code only checks for SIGHASH ACP, SINGLE & NONE. [See Python-Bitcoinlib's code for a Python interpretation](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/bitcoin/core/script.py#L853-L902)

See [this test vector](https://github.com/simcity4242/pybitcointools/blob/master/tests/tx_valid.json#L20-L23), where the hash being validated is `11743b220e9e24e89abd4ff124a2740531fe7d7f9b4e26de14710a532fd543e2`.

FWIW, Pybitcointools needs to have the `txhash` function edited so that instead of `if hashcode:`, it reads `if hashcode is not None:`. The else clause in that function was confusing me, but it appears to be for hashing *signed* transactions (ie to return the TxID)